# Genesis difficulty in yellow paper is different in mainnet

Tags: yellow-paper

Recently I noticed that Difficulty in genesis block is defined as 131072 in yellow paper. It is different as 17,179,869,184  in [mainnet](https://etherscan.io/block/0). Anyone knows why two are different?

[image: yellow paper screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the last release of the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) (BERLIN VERSION fabef25 – 2021-12-02).

According to the yellow paper :

[image: yellow paper : equation 41]

with *H_i* being the block number.

For the genesis block (*H_i* = 0), the difficulty is effectively equal to 2^34 = 17,179,869,184.

However, I do not know where this incorrect value of 131,072 comes from.
Anyway, great find!